# React.js : How to fix Syntax error : unexpected token < in React.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, webpack, package.json

React.js -> Syntax error : Unexpected token and I can't seem to find a solution, all my (.babelrc)presets , webpack.config and package.json seems to be right.

I have been stuck on this from past 1 week and i am not able to find a problem please help I am a beginner

here is my webpack.config.js , package.json and .babelrc respectively

webpack.config.js :- i have checked this out , I cant really seem to find a problem in it , do i have to create more loaders or something please help i am a beginner

```
const WEBPACK = require('webpack');
const PATH = require('path');

module.exports = {
mode: "none",
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
},
context: __dirname,
entry: {
    app: ['./src/index.jsx'], 
},
output : {
    path: PATH.join(__dirname, '/MY_FOLDER_OUTPUT'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
        }
    ]
},

};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "newReact",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "babel": "babel",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "build": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "prod_build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.0.15",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-stage-0": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015","react"],
   "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx"]
}
```

this is index.jsx

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

ReactDOM.render(
      <h1>
        Hello World
      </h1>,
      document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: `entry: {
    app: ['./src/index.jsx'] // app: 
['./MY_FOLDER_INPUT/MY_FILE_INDEX.jsx']` maybe missing a coma ?     
`entry: {
    app: {
         ['./src/index.jsx'], // app: 
         ['./MY_FOLDER_INPUT/MY_FILE_INDEX.jsx']
    }
}`

Comment: sorry does not work

Comment: '<'   from inside ReactDOM.render('<h1>Hello world</h1>',document.getElementByID('app'))

Comment: ERROR in ./src/index.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\newReact\src\index.jsx: Unexpected token (6:6)

      4 | const renderApp = (Component) => {
      5 |     ReactDOM.render(
    > 6 |       <h1>
    |       ^
      7 |         Hello World
      8 |       </h1>,
      9 |       document.getElementById('app')

Comment: isn't the error in index.jsx?

Comment: no i will add index.jsx too wait

Comment: That's an error that's often a red herring. I've seen it many times when there's actually a server error. Are you making any http request, or is the entire app shown there?

Comment: no i am making no such requests , removing the ReactDOM.render command from index.jsx builds perfectly .

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing your own config from scratch ? Starting with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) would take care of all your config

Comment: @Axnyff yeah that works ,  but is there any problem in my code ?